# Which English words place the tip of the tongue between teeth?

Tags: pronunciation

Which English words place the tip of the tongue between teeth?
For example: *other* and *that*

Comment: You give examples, then you ask if the examples exist? It's like asking "are there English words that start with an _a_, like apple?"

Comment: ***Are*** there any English words formed from *only* the letters **A**, **R**, and **E** (in that order, with no repeated letters)?

Comment: Out of the mouth?

Comment: @oerkelens I wanted to make sure that these examples are true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Interdental consonants* are produced by placing the tip of the tongue between the upper and lower front teeth. Examples that use this *th* sound include that, then, thin, there, both, wroth, etc. The tongue may or may not actually protrude past the teeth

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interdental_consonant

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "get the tongue out", but certainly any word with the [old thorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_%28letter%29) (th) sound is typically made almost entirely by pushing the tongue a fair bit forward near the front teeth and blowing air past it (sometimes involving the larynx not at all).

I believe the linguists refer to this as a [voiceless dental frictive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_dental_fricative). Supposedly, some Turkic languages do this as well.